# Intructions for Debian 8.2 net install dual boot with Windows 8.1

Tags: debian, system-installation, dual-boot, raid, window

I cannot prepare dual boot installation in my hp zbook 14, I have windows 8.1 installed and want dual boot with Debian 8.2. I have configured the things for a standard ubuntu installation, preparing a partition for linux, remove windows fast boot,

here is my bios setup:

[image]

[image]

And this are my partitions in windows

[image]

I want to install debian in the disk called debian, the problem that this is RAID and I couldn't install this normally the installation doesn't find the disks only the USB, I want to left windows 8.1 as it it now. How should I proceed

Answer (score 0):

I would first of all urge you to clean up the question quite a bit.

Some things you need to explicitly state :-

a. You haven't shared what kind of raid setup you are having, is this software RAID or a hardware RAID ?

b. You have talked about both ubuntu and Debian in the same breath and question. Could you be explicit in what you want to have ?

c. From your BIOS screenshots, you are not using UEFI and using BIOS only. AFAIK you do not need to need turn on legacy booting.

I would also suggest you to look at https://superuser.com/questions/714856/trying-to-dual-boot-windows-8-1-and-debian-jessie as it is much similar to what you are trying to do, minus the RAID part.  although :-

if you are trying to get rid of MS-Windows altogether then it's a different question.

Please clean up the question as much as possible so it's possible to share an answer that would be helpful to all.

Update - How to know if it is a hardware RAID or software/fakraid. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FakeRaidHowto and https://serverfault.com/questions/9244/how-do-i-differentiate-fake-raid-from-real-raid to get a better idea of what you need to look for to understand what you have.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, i will try to clarify it, first how can I know if it is a software or  hardware RAID?

Comment: Have updated my answer with the query you have raised.